# False reasoning with cantor set and probability.

Tags: probability, cantor-set

Hello I hope you are doing great.

I would like to know your opinion regarding this reasoning.

Assume you that you put a point in the $n$-th iteration of the ternary Cantor set. This set is formed by the union of disjoint intervals. Lets give to each interval the same probability of the point to be in it. So the probability of the point to be in any of the intervals is $\frac{1}{2^n}$. Clearly the probability of the point to be in the $n$-th iteration is $1$.
We continue with this procedure, forcing that the point is indeed in the corresponding iteration of the Cantor set.
If we consider this to the limit set, the Cantor set. The probability of the ball to be in a set (which is a point) is zero, but since we required that the point should be in the Cantor set, the probability of being in it is $1$. Reaching a contradiction.

I know my reasoning is false, but I'm not completely sure why.

Comment: Shrinking an open ball ? mmm I don't see where an open ball is being shrink. The intervals of the iterations of the Cantor set are closed.

Comment: It is not a contradiction. You have continuum many points in limit set, so even though probability of being in particular one is $0$, you can still get $1$ as a probability of being in a whole set (and you will, since it is your whole range set)

Comment: @DonThousand - Unless the ball centers move towards the edge of the starting ball as they shrink, the intersection will not be empty.

Comment: I don't follow your argument. You are picking points, not balls. Where do the balls come in? You are picking points for each $n$, but in the end you are talking about one point in the limit, and claiming it has to be in. How does this ending point relate to the points you picked for each $n$? If you simply choose a point in the Cantor set, it will be in each of the various steps, without any "probability" talk. If it isn't a diadic rational, it will not be an endpoint of any step either. But there is no contradiction to nested open intervals intersecting in a single point.

Comment: "Diadic rational" was wrong in that previous comment - I was mixing it up with a different construction. The Cantor set endpoints have denominators of the form $3^n$, not $2^n$.

Comment: The idea is, given the n-th iteration of the Cantor set, pick a point in it, and for each new iteration you pick a new point. Since the n-th iteration is the disjoint union of $2^n$ intervals, each interval has a probability $\frac{1}{2^n}$ of the point being selected from it.